# Altair: merge multiple identical legends when using resolve_scale to merge color and shape properties

Tags: visualization, altair

Following a frequent issue in Altair:
[merging legends 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68070119/merge-two-legends-in-altair)
[merging legends 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386504/altair-merging-legends-in-layer-charts)
[combining color and shape](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1785)

I want to plot several point series with line plots and point marks visualized both with different colors, shapes, and stroke dashes:
This works as expected when using `resolve_scale`

```
    x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
    mask = np.ones_like(x)
    mask[::2] = 0
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "x": x, 
        "y": np.sin(x)*mask + np.cos(x)*(1-mask),
        "y2": np.sin(2*x)*mask + np.cos(2*x)*(1-mask) ,
        "col": mask
    })
    base= alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True, size=1).encode(
        alt.X("x:Q"),
        color = alt.Color("col:N"),
        shape = alt.Shape("col:N"),
        strokeDash = alt.StrokeDash("col:N")
    ).resolve_scale(color="independent",  shape="independent", strokeDash="independent")
 
    base.encode(alt.Y("y:Q"))
```

[image: single chart]

But when concatenated with other charts with a different y-value multiple identical legends appear:

`base.encode(alt.Y("y:Q")) | base.encode(alt.Y("y2:Q"))`

[image: concatenated chart with identical legends]

I understand this is the purpose of "resolve_scale", would really appreciate a workaround.
not using the resolve_scale method or using it on the concatenated chart would get me a legend with every visualized property (color, shape, etc) set apart.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the color, shape, and strokeDash to one thing: "col:N". If you want them to be independent, then define them as different things.

```
base= alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True, size=1).encode(
    alt.X("x:Q"),
    color = alt.Color("col:N"),
    shape = alt.Shape("col:N"),
    strokeDash = alt.StrokeDash("col:N")
)

h = base.encode(alt.Y("y:Q"), color=alt.value('red')) | base.encode(alt.Y("y2:Q"), color=alt.value('blue')).resolve_scale(color="independent",  shape="independent", strokeDash="independent")
```

as for a workaround, you could go into the h.hconcat[0].encoding and h.hconcat[1].encoding and change the map to be whatever you want for vega-lite to read. At that point I'd just use a different library.

Hopefully this helps.